# How to target a div that contains another div using css only?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In css, if I write

```
.div1 .div2 { 
   display:none; 
}
```

I'm targeting a div having class div2 that is contained in a div having class div1, so div2 will be not displayed.

What if I need to do the inverse, that is not displaying div1?
I mean, how do i target div1 if the only property i know about it is that div1 contains div2?

Comment: This selects div1 only if it contain's a div2 

    .div1 < .div2 { 
           display:none; 
        }

[Source][1]


  [1]: https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: @coozin From the very first sentence of the article you linked: "there are no parent selectors in CSS". They've even bolded it for crying out loud!

Comment: @woestijnrog it difficult to type when there's so much egg on my face